# Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'closure' while using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, closures

I have some problems with my for loops in R. For selected participants (diff.aki.emp1 >0) in the dataset I want that R returns the value of a certain variable (AB_EMP_1).

I tried doing this with a for loop:

```
final <- data.frame()
for (index in 1:nrow(data)) {
  b <- ""
  if (data[row, "diff.aki.emp1"] > 0) {
    b <- "AB_EMP1"
  } else if (data[row, "diff.aki.emp1"] == 0) {
    b <- "NA"
  }
  final = rbind(final, b)
}
```

However, R returns:

Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'closure'

Does anybody have any suggestions where the problem is and how I might fix this?

Comment: You use `row` when I think you mean to use `index`. Also using `mutate()` with `case_when()` is probably a better way to do things, I am not sure `b` is going to do what you think it is going to do.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, you're using `row` instead of `index`.

For future reference, "invalid subscript type 'closure'" usually refers to situations like this. R is assuming that by `row` you mean `base::row()`, since you haven't said what `row` is.

```
final <- data.frame()
for (index in 1:nrow(data)) {
  b <- ""
  if (data[index, "diff.aki.emp1"] > 0) {
    b <- "AB_EMP1"
  } else if (data[index, "diff.aki.emp1"] == 0) {
    b <- "NA"
  }
  final = rbind(final, b)
}
```

The above should work, but for what you're trying to do here I'd *strongly* recommend looking into the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Thanks! This largely fixed the problem. However, it still returns "AB_EMP1" as a character string for each participant instead of the value of the variable. I tried this but it still does not work correctly:

`final <- data.frame()
for (index in 1:nrow(data)) {
  b <- ""
  if (data[index, "diff.aki.emp1"] > 0) {
    b <- data$AB_EMP1
  } else if (data[index, "diff.aki.emp1"] <= 0) {
    b <- "NA"
  }
  final = rbind(final, b)
}`

Comment: `data$AB_EMP1` will return the full column, as you're iterating through the rows you want `data$AB_EMP1[index]` to return the value for the row you are currently on